# Reading Custom errors from Web-api in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to be able to return custom errors from my (self hosted) web-api.

I have the following flag set in the server configuration...

```
HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);      
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

In the server side Controller, I have something like the following

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyDatadata)
{
  // do stuff and received an error back..

  HttpError error = new HttpError("test test");
  error.Add("mycode", "abcd");
  error.Add("mymdetails", "my detailed message");

   return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
}
```

However, in my Javacript doing the Posting, I can't get at any of these errors.

Eg I will have

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'postUri',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

           var ttt = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText).message;

           if (jqXhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('application/json') > -1)    {
               // only parse the response if you know it is JSON
               var error = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
               alert(error.Message);
           } else {
               alert('Fatal error');
           }
       });
```

But jqXhr.responseText is always an empty string, and I can't see the string anywhere else in the data passed back to the .error

When I look at the response in fiddler (raw view), I do see these strings..

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 91
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 01:20:31 GMT

{
"message": "test test",
"mycode": "abcd",
"mymdetails": "my detailed message"
}
```

But I just can't see how to get to these from the Javascript

Would anyone have any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this, looking again, (with a new sample where just using $.post), the data is indeed in the jqXhr.responseText (as other posts have indicated)

Perhaps previously there was a problem on the server side, I was not doing something properly (I created a new sample server to play with web-api 2)